# Toggle Button isnt working for navigation to display html/css/js

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, navbar

My hamburger-button is not working after I click the navigation should pop out but it does not react or do anything, tried to do by the tutorial custom but still it does not work
HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="script.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5599da2de4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>LAMBDA</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid-full-width">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="navbar m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="navbar-brand logo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-links">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Ingredients</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navIcons">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="hamburger-button">
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                            <span class="bar"></span>
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto
 }
header {
    background: url("images/headbg.png");
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height: 750px;/* baigus header nustatyti auto */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 80px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.logo {
    background: url("images/logo.png");
    width:161px;
    height: 99px;
}
.navbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
}
.navbar ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
}
.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar-links ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 35px 20px;
    font-family: GentiumBookBasic;
    font-size:21px;
}
.navicons {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
}
.navIcons ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.navIconas ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fab {
    color:#dab33e;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.navbar-links li:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.hamburger-button {
    display: none;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:30px;
    height:21px;
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    right:0;
}
.hamburger-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .hamburger-button {
        display:flex;
    }
    .navIcons {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        flex-direction:column;
        width:100%;
    }
    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:flex-start;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-links ul li {
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-links.active {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

JS

```
const togglebutton = document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger-button')[0]
const navbarlinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

togglebutton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navbarlinks.classList.toggle('active')
})`
```

I am new to this so just trying it to work. I am new to this so just trying it to work.
https://codepen.io/justinavii/pen/gOMaRex

Comment: Please review your last paragraph. There are lots of repeations.

Answer (score 0):

[navbaritems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEjmT.png)

Your navbar items are there, they are just white text. (#FFF).

I changed the following and they are more visible.

```
.navbar-links ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color:#01C7F5;
    padding: 35px 20px;
    font-family: GentiumBookBasic;
    font-size:21px;
}
```

Comment: Its because i uploaded to codepen without background, nope it isnt it

Comment: I looked at your codepen. Minimize the screen to where the hamburger navbar menu is enabled. When the text color is changed, your menu items now show.